# Making a navbar disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar, nav

I truly hope this question have not been asked before.

First of all, I wanted my navbar to appear after a specific number of pixels and I found that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 725) {
                $('#nav-principale').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#nav-principale').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

    }); })(jQuery);   </script>
```

And it worked. Now, I'm looking for a way to make my navbar, which is fixed at the top of the screen, disappear, if it's possible, after a specific number of pixels.

It might be really easy, but I have no knowledge in Javascript/jquery.

Thanks for your help,
Zhyrmar

Comment: You can probably just do `$('#nav-principale').css('visibility', 'hidden');` once you've reached a specific number of pixels.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a specific number of pixels"?

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck, I don't really know how to explain it, but when the user scroll to, like the 4000px, the nav will disappear. Daan Heskes already answered though, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (($(this).scrollTop() > 725) && ($(this).scrollTop() < 1025)) {
            $('#nav-principale').fadeIn(500);
        } else { 
            $('#nav-principale').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It will fade in whenever scrolled between 725 px and 1025 px, otherwise it fades out.

---

Also note that you don't need both `(function($)` { and `$(document).ready(function(){`. It's both waiting for the document to get load.